# iPhone Background Services Development

Tags: iphone, notifications, jailbreak, background-service

I am developing an iphone application and I think that it's business logic requires a service to be always running in background.

The service needed is to get the acceleration of the device and notify or perform a certain action when that acceleration becomes a certain value.

Is that allowable in the Apple policies, or is there any idea about a solution?

What cydia development possibilities to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dbramhall left out one important thing:

You can't guarantee that your app won't be killed, the OS can kill apps that are in the background at will if it requires more memory.

So if at all possible i wouldn't rely on making sure it can run its process in the background and before you ask "How can i stop this?". Well you shouldn't I've never tried it myself because i don't know the effects it has on the OS.

Also if you stop it from being killed in the Background, if it is going to be on the app store then it won't pass evaluation process, because it breaks the OS

Comment: Is cydia open tool for development can help me ?

Comment: i believe cydia is the "iTunes" of jailbroken iPhones. So im unsure of what you mean by your comment

Answer (score 0):

Well, an application can run in the background and Apple perfectly accepts this however the user will obviously be be able to close the application (or should be able to) via the multi-tasking bar and this will end the application. Period.

Apple will not accept an application that runs constantly regardless of whether the user has is in background state as this drains the battery, heats the device etc. So an application can run in the background so long as the user can quit it when close it from the multi-tasking bar however it cannot continue to run after the user closed it via multi-tasking - if it does continue, Apple will reject the application.

Also, see 2.16 of the Apple Store review guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality

Comment: thanks, is that any way to force the iOS to do that with ignore apple policies or to make the idea with different way ?

Comment: From what I'm aware, no but you can use: application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:
applicationWillEnterForeground:
applicationWillTerminate:

Comment: I did , but i cannot get the location and speed from when enter background